# IMAP how to login with AUTH=LOGIN in console with OpenSSL

Tags: authentication, console, openssl, imap

I have seen some servers that returns

> AUTH=LOGIN

when I request the CAPABILITY of the IMAP server e.g:

> 1 CAPABILITY
>
> CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+

How can I find more information about `AUTH=LOGIN` and how could I use it to login directly in the console on the server?

I tried [googling it](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22auth%3Dlogin%22+imap&), but wasn't successful. And I would like to implement this Login format in my JAVA IMAP client.

Comment: Which IMAP server software? Was it `dovecot` or `courier` or `cyrus` or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOGIN SASL mechanism is very similar to the PLAIN mechanism, but it takes two steps to authenticate:

```
CLIENT: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER: VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT: am9l
SERVER: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT: bXkgc2VyY3JldA==
```

Which, after base64 decoding translates to:

```
CLIENT: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER: Username:
CLIENT: joe
SERVER: Password:
CLIENT: my secret
```

The specification says that challenges from the server should be `User Name` and `Password`, but:

> Note: There is at least one widely deployed client which requires
>      that the challenge strings transmitted by the server be "Username:"
>      and "Password:" respectively.  For this reason, server
>      implementations MAY send these challenge strings instead of those
>      listed above.

There is no password encryption/hashing involved so you may test both sides quite easilly, for unencrypted communication use `netcat` for encrypted `openssl s_client` or `openssl s_server`.

Note that the example above lacks the used protocol necessities as this part is common to all protocols you may need (SMTP/POP3/IMAP...). The actual communication must still follow the protocol specifications:

IMAP

```
1 AUTH LOGIN
VXNlcm5hbWU6
am9l
UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bXkgc2VyY3JldA==
```

SMTP

```
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
am9l
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bXkgc2VyY3JldA==
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an obsolete, non-standard extension. It is not listed in the [IANA registry of IMAP capabilities](https://www.iana.org/assignments/imap-capabilities/imap-capabilities.xhtml). It comes from an [obsolete `draft-murchison-sasl-login-00`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-murchison-sasl-login-00) (see the [IANA list of SASL authentication schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/sasl-mechanisms/sasl-mechanisms.xhtml)).

It does not bring any new features over the existing [`AUTH=PLAIN`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616) or IMAP's standard [`LOGIN` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.3).